# Python Copy specified lines from text file

Tags: python, copy, lines

This is the full Sample for the code that i needed
I have edited the full post with the sample text files
inputs and outputs

Text file :-

```
Mohammed
Ahmed
Mansour
Sami
Sameer
Ukhlof
Asfar
Virus
Ameer
AbuAlameer
Ismail
Belal
Heba
Mama
Papa
```

Sample Input :-

```
Enter a name : Ukhlof
Enter How much names you want to copy before that name : 10
```

Output :

```
From Up :-
Mohammed
Ahmed
Mansour
Sami
Sameer
Ukhlof

From Down :-
Belal
Heba
Mama
Papa
```

Your Code output :-

```
From up:
Mohammed
Ahmed
Mansour
Sami
Sameer
From Down:
Papa
```

Comment: Please edit sample input and expected output into your post

Comment: Hi, I have added the sample , this sample of course if it is more than the x variable , if less it will show only the up results

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I have added the sample , did you get the idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import collections

def get(infilepath, name, n):
    d = collections.deque(maxlen=n)
    with open(infilepath) as infile:
        line = infile.readline()
        lines = 1
        while line:
            word = line.strip()
            if word == name:
                print("From up:")
                for item in d:
                    print(item)
                print(word)
                break
            d.append(word)
            line = infile.readline()
            lines += 1
        print("From Down:")

        if n-lines > 0:
            n -= lines
            d = collections.deque(maxlen=n)
            while word:
                d.append(word)
                word = infile.readline().strip()
                if not word:
                    break
            for word in d:
                print(word)
```

Usage:

```
def main():
    name = input("Enter a name: ")
    n = int(input("How many lines? "))
    infilepath = 'blah'
    get(infilepath, name, n)
```

Input File:

```
Mohammed
Ahmed
Mansour
Sami
Sameer
Ukhlof
Asfar
Virus
Ameer
AbuAlameer
Ismail
Belal
Heba
Mama
Papa
```

Output:

```
In [184]: main()
Enter a name: Ukhlof
How many lines? 10
From up:
Mohammed
Ahmed
Mansour
Sami
Sameer
Ukhlof
From Down:
Belal
Heba
Mama
Papa
```

Comment: I have created a loop and used your code inside it ,  the first process was perfect , but when move to the next entire in the loop the From Dow list decrease by the number of the lines in from up list for each time the loop starts ?